Movie from 90s or early 2000s of boy drinking a potion and becoming a wooden-like
I am trying to remember a movie from the '90s or early 2000s that creeped me and my brother out when we were too young.
I remember a scene in an empty or abandoned circus where a boy drinks some potion from a bottle and becomes a wooden-like creature. There was another boy and an older man, I believe. They were in a forest afterwards.

Could you explain what you mean by "wooden-like"?

Also, take a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/59154 for tips on writing a good story-id question; the more details you give, the more likely someone is to identify it.

Stupid suggestion, but Pinocchio was wooden-like and in a circus. Drinking stuff.

@JohnK.  My first thought too, though it doesn't really fit.  But ... Pinocchio was "wooden-like" as much as the water coming out of the tap is "water-like" :-)

@Basya well, boy-like wood or wood-like boy. Who are we to say ...

Bit of a long shot but there was a Metz (schnapps) ad which aired in the UK in 2000 that featured a man in a forest luring a young man to drink from a bottle, which turns him into a wooden puppet.
The whole atmosphere of the ad is quite creepy.
There's no circus, but I think there were a series of similar "Judderman" ads so another may be a closer match, if the style of this one seems familiar.



